# Variable passing on Backbone template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I just started learning 'Backbone.js', I am currently following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk)  video tutorial. For templating, I just kept my template to be simple like this -

```
<script type="text/template" id="songlist_template">
<%_.each(songs, function(song){});  %>
<h1>Loaded</h1>
</script>
```

and my view extended as-

```
var SongList=Backbone.View.extend({
el:'.page',
render: function(){
    var that=this;
    var songs=new Songs();
    songs.fetch({
        success:function (){
            var temp=_.template($("#songlist_template").html());
            var html=temp(songs);
            that.$el.html(html);
            },
        error: function (collection, response, options) {
            alert("error!! "+response.responseText); 
            }})
}});
```

Everything is perfect until I reach templating section where *console log* says-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: songs is not defined is not defined.
```

According to [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) , I think my template syntax is OK and I have passed the correct **fetched data**.  Furthermore I have also defined variable **songs**. It would be helpful if someone can point it out my mistake.

Complete code [here](http://pastebin.com/4U7n3VH9) and json file [here](http://pastebin.com/pKsg8M6L).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix your issue pass the songs as array **temp({songs:songs.models})**

in success callback you could add the parameter songs

```
  success:function (songs){
            var temp=_.template($("#songlist_template").html());
            var html=temp({songs:songs.models});
            that.$el.html(html);
            },
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

> The options hash takes success and error callbacks which will both be passed (collection, response, options) as arguments

Comment: I tried this way too,  but still getting same error.

Comment: to fix your issue pass the songs as array temp({songs:songs})

Comment: for your code,  to get it to work pass variable as temp({songs : songs.models}) to the template

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Underscore's [`template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> When you evaluate a template function, pass in a data object that has **properties** corresponding to the template's **free variables**

(Emphasis mine)

What @VladuIonut is trying to - correctly - explain is that you must pass in an object containing the properties that you reference in your template.

If your collection of songs doesn't have a property also called `songs` for the template to use, it will fail with this undefined ReferenceError.

Your template call should look like this:

```
var html=temp({
    "songs": songs
});
```